# How do I make `origin/HEAD` work with partial fetch settings?

Tags: git, git-fetch

In a typical "regular" git clone, one ends up with `.git/config` as follows:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:orgname/reponame.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

and then `git show origin/HEAD` works fine.

However, I don't want all branches to be fetched, only `prod` and ones prefixed with `jakub/`, so my `.git/config` is as follows:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:orgname/reponame.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/prod:refs/remotes/origin/prod
    fetch = +refs/heads/jakub/*:refs/remotes/origin/jakub/*
```

(I didn't do a `git clone`, but created a `.git/config` like above, and then did `git fetch`).

However, with that setup, `git show origin/HEAD` no longer works:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

I tried to add the following to `.git/config` but it doesn't work:

```
    fetch = +refs/heads/HEAD:refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

```
$ git fetch
fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/HEAD
```

What's the proper way to make `origin/HEAD` work with partial fetching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HEAD branch of the remote repository is one of the branches configured in your fetch refspecs, then this should work:

```
git remote set-head origin -a
```

This will query the remote for its HEAD and set `origin/HEAD` to point to the corresponding remote-tracking branch in your repository.

If the remote HEAD points to a branch thst is not covered by your fetch refspec, then you would have to add a fetch refspec for that branch, fetch it, and then run the above command.

Answer (score 1):

The name `origin/HEAD` is a symbolic ref.  Aside from the initial `git clone`, the user-facing command for working with this is `git remote set-head`.

For a symbolic ref to work, the *target* of that symbolic ref must exist.  The target is shown on the right of the `->` in `git branch -r` or similar output:

> ```
>   origin/HEAD -> origin/master
> ```

Here, the target of `origin/HEAD` is `origin/master`.  If I did not have the name `origin/master` in my own clone here, `origin/HEAD` would not work.

So: what you need is to fetch and create `origin/thing`, where *`thing`* is the name of the "default branch" in the repository over at `origin`.  Since:

> ```
>     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> ```

creates and updates a remote-tracking name for each branch name in that repository, whichever branch name is the *default* branch<sup>1</sup> will<sup>2</sup> exist here as `origin/thing` and it all works the way you want.

When you make a *single-branch clone*,<sup>3</sup> however, you instruct your Git to fetch only *one specific* branch name.  Adding more branches (with `git remote set-branches`) lets you add to the collection.

For Git to *create* `origin/HEAD` in the first place, Git demands that the target actually exist.  So after, e.g.:

```
git clone --single-branch -b next https://github.com/git/git
```

I get a new clone of the Git repository for Git in which only two names exist:

```
$ git branch -a
* next
  remotes/origin/next
```

Note the lack of an `origin/HEAD`.  But now comes the guessing game: which remote-tracking name(s) should I *add?*  There are a few ways to find out, including using either of `git ls-remote --symref` or `git remote set-head`:

```
$ git ls-remote --symref origin HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master  HEAD
c03801e19cb8ab36e9c0d17ff3d5e0c3b0f24193        HEAD
$ git remote set-head origin --auto
error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
origin/HEAD set to master
```

The last output line is a lie: because I don't *have* an `origin/master`, `origin/HEAD` *did not* get set to `master`.  But the output here shows which branch I need to "git remote set-branches --add":

```
$ git remote set-branches --add origin master
$ git fetch origin
From github.com:git/git
 * [new branch]            master     -> origin/master
$ git branch -r
  origin/master
  origin/next
$ git remote set-head origin --auto
origin/HEAD set to master
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/next
```

Now it is done.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git uses the term *default branch* to mean "whichever branch name is stored in `HEAD` in a repository that you cloned".  GitHub in particular let you *change* this by navigating to the repository in their web interface and using various clicky buttons and such to choose any of the branch names.  This of course assumes you have permission to set them.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, *will* is too strong: the default branch setting in `HEAD` is up to the server host system, and Google Code, for some reason known only to the Google Code people, do not provide a way to set this—and the setting is stuck on "master" for many repositories that have only a "main".  In this case, `origin/HEAD` points to a nonexistent name.

<sup>3</sup>Note that while `git clone --single-branch` is the obvious way to do this, `git clone --depth` turns on single-branch-ness.  Note, too, that the term for this is *single-branch* clone, even if it's a two or three branch clone; *partial clone* refers to a new feature that's gradually coming to Git.

Comment: Very detailed answer, thanks!